# An efficient way to group, sort, and pivot rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have recently started learning PySpark for Big Data Analysis. I have the following problem and am trying to find a better way to achieve this. I'll walk you through the problem below.

Given the pyspark dataframe below:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | DateTime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | yyy | 01.04.2019 | 100 |
| B | D | yyy | 05.04.2019 | 200 |
| B | D | xxx | 09.04.2019 | 50 |
| A | C | yyy | 08.04.2019 | 600 |
| A | C | xxx | 02.04.2019 | 580 |

I would want to group by columns - Col1, Col2, Col3 and sort by DateTime Descending in each of the groups

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | DateTime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | xxx | 02.04.2019 | 580 |
| A | C | yyy | 08.04.2019 | 600 |
| A | C | yyy | 01.04.2019 | 100 |
| B | D | xxx | 09.04.2019 | 50 |
| B | D | yyy | 05.04.2019 | 200 |

Then, from each of these sorted groups take the topmost row (i.e latest in DateTime)

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | DateTime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | xxx | 02.04.2019 | 580 |
| A | C | yyy | 08.04.2019 | 600 |
| B | D | xxx | 09.04.2019 | 50 |
| B | D | yyy | 05.04.2019 | 200 |

Finally, pivot Col3 values and use the 'Value'

| Col1 | Col2 | xxx | yyy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 580 | 600 |
| B | D | 50 | 200 |

How would I go around achieving this in an efficient way with lesser steps? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this:

First Question

```
df.orderBy(df.Col1.asc(),df.Col2.asc(),df.Col3.asc()).show(truncate=False)
```

or

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("DATA")
spark.sql("select Col1, Col2, Col3, DateTime, Value from DATA ORDER BY Col1 asc").show(truncate=False)
```

Second question- Because you ordered them, drop duplicates

```
df.dropDuplicates(["Col1","Col2","Col3"]).show()
```

Let us now pivot

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.groupBy(["Col1","Col2"]).pivot("Col3").agg(psf.max("Value")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_df.withColumn("row_no", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Col1", "Col2", "Col3").orderBy("DateTime")))
  .filter(col("row_no") === 1)
  .select("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Value")
  .groupBy("Col1", "Col2")
  .pivot("Col3")
  .agg(collect_set("Value"))
  .show
```

I haven't handled DateTime as date for sorting, so you can do that for yourself but will get the correct result